# Executing pyspark df.join command from a file

Tags: python-2.7, dataframe, pyspark

I have multiple pyspark data frames that I want to join.

```
finalDF = df1.join(df2, 'key2', 'left_outer')
.join(df3, 'key3')
.join(df4, 'key4')
.join(df5, 'key5')
```

Now, I may not have all the data frames (df2-5). So, I want to only join those that exist which let's say I can programmatically  find.

I want to build a dynamic df.join command and execute depending on the availability of df2-df5.

I thought of building/writing the command into a file (using if else) depending on my needs/availability and then executing the file as a pyspark command. Is it even feasible to do it that way?

Or, is there a better approach? Please suggest. TIA.

Comment: If you know which don't exist, why not use an if/else: `finalDF = df1; if df2_exists: finalDF = finalDF.join(df2, 'key2') ...`

Comment: That is my plan for now. Since it would mean multiple steps if all df's exist, I thought, may be, there is some elegant way other than if/else.

Comment: It would not mean multiple steps as spark is lazy. Look at `finalDF.explain()` at the end and you'll see that it will do all of the (valid) joins in parallel rather than serially.

Comment: Thanks. That is the part I missed (performing joins in parallel). If you can provide your comment as answer - I will accept the same. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know which DataFrames exist, you can use a simple `if/else`:

```
finalDF = df1
if df2_exists:
    finalDF = finalDF.join(df2, 'key2', 'left_outer')
if df3_exists:
    finalDF = finalDF.join(df3, 'key3')
if df4_exists:
    finalDF = finalDF.join(df4, 'key4')
if df5_exists:
    finalDF = finalDF.join(df5, 'key5')
```

This will not mean multiple steps as spark is lazy. If you look at the output of `finalDF.explain()`, you will see that it will do all of the joins in parallel rather than serially.